# Java dar color a la cabecera de una tabla

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Estoy intentando dar color a la cabecera de un `JTable` y no tengo idea de cual es mi fallo, agradezco la ayuda

Dejo parte del código:

```
// estilo jtable
jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD,12));
jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(32, 136, 203));
jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
jTabla_registro.setRowHeight(25);
```

Estoy haciendo la prueba para tratar de conseguir lo que deseo y de esa forma sencilla no logro cambiar el color de fondo de la cabecera sigue siendo el color de por defecto...

Dejo el código completo utilizando la función  `Cambiartema()` para cambiar los colores del aspecto de Nimbus:

```
public class Filtro extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection con2 = null;

 public void cambiartema(){
    
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(32,136,203));
                    UIManager.put("control", Color.PINK); 
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtro.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    
    }

public Filtro() {
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("Filtro");
        setSize(1000,600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        VaciarTabla();
        verdatos();
        
        cambiartema(); 
        
        jTabla_registro.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        
        jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 12));
        jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
        jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(32, 136, 203));
        jTabla_registro.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTabla_registro.setRowHeight(25);
        
    }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606852/change-background-color-of-jtable

Comment: Funciona para cambiar el fondo pero no la cabecera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más probable es que tengas como look and feel Nimbus, así que una opción es modificar los colores por defecto del L&F para que quede a como tú quieres sin que pierda la apariencia.

Básicamente reemplazas el valor que usa por defecto para que todos los componentes que se pinten con un estilo se pinten de otra forma mediante:

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", Color.CYAN);
```

Por ejemplo si usamos el siguiente código:

```
try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", Color.CYAN);
                    UIManager.put("control", Color.PINK); 
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

La interfaz gráfica se verá algo así:

[image: cambio de colores de Nimbus L&F]

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700758/how-to-change-background-color-for-nimbus-look-and-feel-using-java

Comment: He utilizado el mismo código con colocares diferentes y no conseguí ningún cambio, no tengo idea de que pueda estar haciendo mal. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Lo primero que estás haciendo mal es no compartir tu código completo ([mcve]), tampoco somos adivinos ( aún ) :(

Comment: gracias por el comentario, fue agregado.

Comment: Yo el cambiar tema se lo puse en el main, antes de todo. Inténtalo así y nos dices que pasa. Saludos.

Comment: Listo amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, disculpa las novatadas que soy nuevo en el foro, Gracias...

Answer (score 1):

El código funciona y hace el cambio de color de fondo a las cabeceras de la tabla, el problema lo encontré con el tema visual *Nimbus* el cual utiliza `Painter` para renderizar los encabezados y que se noten con efectos y tal por lo cual va a ignorar de cierta forma la instrucción `setBackground`, ello no sucede con *Metal*, *GTK* o el que traiga el sistema operativo.

Lo que se me ocurre a priori es alterar el valor del color por default que *Nimbus* le aplica a los encabezados de los `JTable` el cual se llama internamente '*nimbusBlueGrey*'.

Entonces en alguna parte de tu código llama a:

```
private void verificarTema() {
  try {
    if(UIManager.getLookAndFeel().toString().contains("Nimbus"))
      UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey",new Color(32,136,203));
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Lo anterior modifica valores preestablecidos dentro de éste *LookAndFeel* a través de `put` usando una forma de pares *Key - Value*.

Hay muchos mas de estos valores [Nimbus Defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) para conocer.

Comment: Buenas anteriormente, pensé que esto solucionaba el problema, en parte si pero me trae un nuevo problema, con este código se ven modificados los demás componentes como los Jdatechooser y botones de todas las ventanas o jframe, alguna solución para esto ?